# Resharper 9 and Jasmine 2.x references

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, visual-studio-2015, resharper-9.0

in the past I have used webstorm, karma, jasmine and phantom to run js tests. I have to now run tests within VS2015 and opted for resharper/jasmine and phantom js. I have my tests running ok and its actually looking good. The only gripe I have is that with karma you could specify wild card references and hence using a config all the referenced dependent js files are in one location. Now Im having to specify references in every spec file that I create. Is there an better way of doing this?

e.g. at the top of my spec file I have a couple of these:

```
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine/jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine/jasmine-html.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/jasmine/boot.js"/>
///<reference path="~/Scripts/angular-core/angular.js"/>
```

and each file has much of the same references copied and pasted.

As a side note -  I have also noticed that under the scripts folder in my mvc app there is an auto gen _references.js file that seems to have all my referenced files in it (though some paths are relative) - not sure that that is!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

First off, R# 9.2 automatically loads in the needed jasmine files, so they're not necessary as references, and additionally if you load e.g. 2.3 jasmine as references, it breaks the css on the displayed page.

What I found that works well is to create a testReferences.js with the stuff I want in all unit tests, and then reference it with additional references.

testReferences.js:

```
/// <reference path="~/wwwroot/lib/angular/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="~/wwwroot/lib/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js" />
/// <reference path="~/wwwroot/app/app.js" />
```

Unit Test:

```
/// <reference path="~/scripts/testReferences.js" />
/// <reference path="~/wwwroot/app/Production/productionQueueController.js" />
```